# How to extract only character values from a mixed variable list(num+char) in sas

Tags: sas, etl

In a varible list there are numeric as well as character values are there, how can I get only character values from it in sas. example dataline are here in only one variable list VAR1 there are values e.g:

```
123
xyz
457
abc
789
frf
233
gth
...
664
fgd
```

I have to extract only those character values(abc, xyz etc) from that whole dataline, How can I get.

Comment: Are these eight separate variables or one variable with eight values in it?

Comment: there are eight values in one variable

Comment: Numbers are characters too. A correct term would be non numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is working fine for me:
data want; 
    set have; 
    if prxmatch('/\d+\s*$/',VAR1)>0 then delete;
run;

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use this

```
data _null_;
    var1 = '123, xyz, 456, abc, 789, frf, 233, gth';
    var2 = compbl(compress(var1, '', 'ka'));
    put var2=;
run;
```

EDIT:

```
data _null_;
    var1 = '123 xyz 456 abc 789 frf 233 gth
            123 xyz 456 abc 789 frf 233 gth
            123 xyz 456 abc 789 frf 233 gth';
    var2 = compbl(compress(var1, '', 'ka'));
    put var2;
run;
```

Comment: what if VAR1 has more than thousand values not eight values, then what can I do? and the commas before were only to seperate values, There is no comma in the dataset.

Comment: It does not matter. See my edited answer. More values and no commas.

Comment: thanks,                                                                                                                    
        data want;
 set have;
 if prxmatch('/\d+\s*$/',VAR1)>0 then delete;
run; but this answer is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not abundantly clear, however, if the individual values are in a single column you can use `VERIFY` instead of the more complicated `PRXMATCH`

```
data have;
input var1 $; datalines;
123
xyz
457
abc
789
frf
233
gth
...
664
fgd
;

data want;
  set have;
  where 0 = verify (trim(var1), '0123456789');
run;
```

**[VERIFY](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0aesccozrvg19n1bg83z1jb9nid.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)**

> Returns the position of the first character in a string that is not in specified data strings. 
>   ...
>
> **Details**
>   The VERIFY function returns the position of the first character in source that is not present in any excerpt. If VERIFY finds every character in source in at least one excerpt, VERIFY returns a 0.